# How Can One Transfer Xcode 4 Code Snippets from One Machine to Another

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I've got some user code snippets in my Xcode 4 which I would like to copy to another machine and share with other developers.  Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Desperately looking for an answer to this question. It does not seem to be stored in the usual folders...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Ah found it, they are saved at:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/
```

Each one is a plist file. In contrast to Xcode 3 there is now one file per snippet.
There is no harm done in renaming them to more useful file names, Xcode will not mind.
In fact, my whole CodeSnippets folder is a git repository and many devs share their favorites on github. Mine are at https://github.com/lichtschlag/Xcode-4-Code-Snippets.

Comment: This is in users/ username / isn't it

Comment: The tilde (~) refers to the current user's home directory.

Comment: I made a script which will configure Xcode to use iCloudDrive for your CodeSnippets location. This is useful for sharing snippets across multiple dev machines. https://github.com/zakkhoyt/XcodeSnippets/blob/master/xcode_snippets

Comment: this is out dated

Answer (score 45):

As noted by NSSplendid, they're stored in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/`.

You can use Dropbox to sync them; I use this technique to synchronize my key bindings and archives between computers.

Follow these steps:

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Move your CodeSnippets directory to your Dropbox. For example, let's say you moved them to `~/Dropbox/CodeSnippets`
3. Let Dropbox upload them.
4. Pause Dropbox's syncing.
5. Move them back to where Xcode stores them.
6. Create a symbolic link into Dropbox: `ln -s ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets ~/Dropbox/CodeSnippets`.
7. Resume Dropbox syncing.
8. Relaunch Xcode.

On your other computer:

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Let Dropbox download everything, if it hasn't yet.
3. Pause Dropbox syncing.
4. Remove your local Xcode user data: `rm -R ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`.
5. Move your UserData from Dropbox to Xcode: `mv ~/Dropbox/CodeSnippets ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`.
6. Create a symbolic link from your UserData to DropBox: `ln -s ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets ~/Dropbox/CodeSnippets`.
7. Resume Dropbox syncing.
8. Relaunch Xcode.

The convolutions are necessary because Xcode will not follow a symlink, but Dropbox will. Dropbox will treat that symlink exactly as if the directory was actually there.

This is not perfect; you will probably have to quit Xcode to have it recognize new snippets.

I sync my entire UserData directory, which gets me synchronized key bindings, named tabs, font & color schemes and code snippets. To do this, move and ln ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData instead.

Comment: Use dropbox a lot and this has helped me SO MUCH, thanks you!

Comment: Dropbox apparently will no longer follow a symlink outside the Dropbox folder.  https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/symlinks

Answer (score 4):

I made a Xcode plugin for synchronizing snippets with a git repository.

With it, you can share snippets on different computers and even among a team.

The ACCodeSnippetRepository plugin is available on [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) and [Github](https://github.com/acoomans/ACCodeSnippetRepositoryPlugin).

Comment: No, only git repositories are supported for now. I intended to support gist as well but didn't have the time. It may come in a future release (or you can implement it and I'll pull your requests)

Answer (score 1):

They are located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets/

It's good practice use version control for that if those snippets are meaningful to you.
Than it's sufficient to do periodic commits and push changes to remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way to migrate your CodeSnippets :-**

1. Open Finder -> Click on Go from menu bar (Hold option key it will give you option of Library , Open Library) -> Developer -> Xcode -> UserData.
2. Now you ill see the folder CodeSnippets, just copy the folder and back it up anywhere you want. Path:- (/Users/yourUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets)

[image]

3. After you backup, just go to the new machine(Make sure Xcode is completely closed) copy the CodeSnippets folder which you did backup, and paste it. Open Xcode and you will find the snippets that you made (Pressing Command + Shift + L).

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I'm not gonna give you exact answer, but rather a guideline: code blocks, completions, project/file templates (from File -> New...) are held in separate files probably somewhere in `[~]/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared` or somewhere else. So my final point is - search through files for snippets or their titles and I am pretty sure you will find a location where all user made code snippets are stored.

If that's the case - then just copy over those files to other machine, restart Xcode there and you should be good.